# LAMP from 12.04 CD on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, 12.04, lamp

Is it possible (and how) to install Ubuntu server 16.04 without LAMP and after installation running a LAMP install from Ubuntu 12.04 CD?
Maybe bringing up the package installation menu like during installation?

I have some project done in PHP5.3, but it's not working properly on version 5.6. What will be the simplest way to setup the old LAMP?

Answer (score 0):

This will probably not work. 12.04 is *ancient*, and have different versions of essential libraries. I can't imagine that a PHP version linked against the libraries for 12.04 will run on 16.04.

As I see it, there's two ways to accomplish this:

1. Install 12.04, perhaps in a VM.
2. Compile PHP 5.3 from source on 16.04.

Either of these options will work. Either option is a really, really bad idea. There's a lot of security problems that are patched in later PHP releases, and you should investigate why the application is not running on PHP 5.6, and fix those issues.